# Reading IBM MQ into Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ibm-mq, apache-storm, flume

I have HDP2.1 cluster . I want to get the  data from IBM MQ directly into Hadoop,Exploring tools that can do this for me

Which tool will be better in terms of performance and at production level?
I checked flume(JMS source) but not sure if will work at production level.

Storm doesn't connect well to IBM MQ as per http://hortonworks.com/blog/discover-hdp-2-2-apache-kafka-apache-storm-stream-data-processing/

Is there any other production level tool that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Streams can do this quite easily.  The product is shipped with two toolkits to do this:

1)  streamsx.messaging (http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.messaging/) - This toolkit provides a JMSSource operator for reading data from Websphere MQ

2)  streamsx.hdfs (http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.hdfs/)

You can construct a Streams application like this:

JMSSource -> some processing -> HDFS2FileSink

For more information about IBM Streams, you may want to check out this site:
http://ibmstreams.github.io/

Hope this helps.